# Why do I get an error on the last line of installing psycopg2-2.4.6 within Python 2.7 in Windows Vista 64?

Tags: python-2.7

Why do I get an error on the last line of installing psycopg2-2.4.6 within  Python 2.7 in Windows Vista 64?
like this
raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
ValueError: [u'path']

I have installed msdn before this installation.

because before installing msdn it shows an error of bat file missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building python module from source can be quite a pain on Windows. Try installing visual studio epxress edition 2008, that will install missing compilers and adapt configuration. If you still have error, install the binary from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#psycopg (I suggest you bookmark this page, it is VERY useful for Python devs on Windows)